# Difficulty in displaying kml file with extension as .pl in android

Tags: android, python, xml, download, kml

I am developing an android application using google maps. I have to display some text information and some pictures related to the text. For this purpose I have a `.pl` file where the information is written as `kml`. 
I know how to extract information using `sax` parser from an `xml`, however I am not able to decide as how to go ahead with `.pl` file. 
I thought of downloading them into sd card and saving them as `xml` extension so the usual `xml` parsing can be used. But I don't know how to do this.
Kindly help or if there is some other way it can be done please tell.

Thanks,
Astha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KML is Keyhole Markup Language (KML) is an XML notation for expressing geographic annotation 
Download sample project which can parse kml data from the following url.

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/downloads/

Thanks
Deepak